# Rao-Blackwell theorem and conditional distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

> Let $X_1,..,X_n$ random sample of $X\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ with
>   $f(x;\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{1}{\lambda}x}I_{[0,\infty]}(x)$
>
> i) Find a unbiased estimator of $\lambda$ based only in
>   $X_{(1)}=\min(X_i)$
>
> ii) Apply the Rao-Blackwell theorem for find a
>   estimator better that you find in i)

For i) I find that $\hat{\lambda}=nX_{(1)}$ is unbiased estimator for $\lambda$. Now for the part ii) that is the problem.

I know that $f(x;\lambda)\in$ the exponential family and $T=\sum X_i$ is a complete and sufficient statistic. Then since $\phi_T=E[nX_{(1)}|\sum X_i]$ produces a unbiased estimator, then it needs to be UMVUE.

So I calculated the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound and find $\text{var}_\lambda\geq \frac{\lambda^2}{n}$, finally I just take $\phi_T=\frac{\sum X_i}{n}$

Now my doubts are:
i)My reasoning is correct?

ii)I always need to calculate conditional distribution?

iii)Is there any simple way to find this conditional?

iv)How could I find the conditional in this case?

I am unable to find that conditional

Comment: The purpose of this question of this question was to make you calculate $\Phi_T$, which is, as you correctly guessed, $\sum X_i/n$. 

Nowhere did the question ask you to calculate Cramer-Rao lower bound...

While you obtained the answer in another fashion, because the exponential distribution example is so typical, you missed the point of the question entirely.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/153016/119261.